# Without using a wrapper class, can I load multiple (non-hierarcical) children classes in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Right now I have a class that gathers and holds information about a specific program that runs in multiple instances on my machine streaming a few radio stations.

What I waned to do was have separate children classes that have different aspects of what I'd want to do.  For example

- Child Class 1, allow sending commands to the running instance
- Child Class 2, query the program for pulling meta data and playlist history

Now most scripts only would do one of those things, with the except of a few which I'd want to have access to BOTH of the children classes.

Is there any way without having Child 1 extend Child 2 which extends the Parent, to have an instance which includes both children, or is hierarchical the only option in PHP for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can move this logic to traits (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and just include them in required classes. Make sense?

Comment: That could possibly work.  I'm seeing where it says how to use them, but I do have another question.  Does the `use traitName;`  have to occur in the base of the class, or could I have a method which calls that?  I'm guessing from context that I cannot?  The reason I ask is if it's loaded no matter what, I'm not saving anything vs including the child/trait in the class to begin with and just putting it's "constructor" behind an initialization method.